# How to round all values in a Pandas DataFrame IN PLACE?

Tags: pandas

Why would you want it? For example, to round all values in a DataFrame but to retain all its assigned attributes:

```py
>>> df
          0         1
0  0.132565  0.147642
1  0.504050  0.451487

>>> df.name
'foo'

>>> df.update(df.round(2))
>>> df
      0     1
0  0.13  0.15
1  0.50  0.45

>>> df.name
'foo'
```

While *returning* a new DataFrame with rounded values gives this error upon calling the DataFrame's attribute:

```
>>> df
          0         1
0  0.132565  0.147642
1  0.504050  0.451487

>>> df.name
'foo'

>>> df = df.round(2)
>>> df
      0     1
0  0.13  0.15
1  0.50  0.45

>>> df.name
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: FWIW, giving dataframes attributes like that is a bad idea for exactly the reason you indicate.; they aren't permanent. If you want a DataFrame to have a name, consider naming the index, or storing it in a dict where the key is the DataFrame name.

Comment: @ALollz Would it be fine to use an instance of a custom class with attributes storing the DataFrame, its name and what have you? Is it a proper approach?

Comment: yeah I think that's probably a better alternative, though again you can't really pickle class objects so you won't have permanence across I/O operations the same way you would with doing `pd.DataFrame().to_pickle()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `update` method to rewrite the data in the original DataFrame with the return value of the `round` method:

```
df.update(df.round())
```

This approach (using the `update` function) can be used with other Pandas methods that don't work *in place*.